# FirestoreRecyclerAdapter no virtual method getDocument

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I am currently converting my Firebase UI components to Firestore UI components. When building the `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` and manually call the `adapter.startListening()` or initialize it via `new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder().setLifeCycleOwner()` I stumble on the following fatal exception.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: packagename, PID: 3129
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getDocument()Lcom/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot; in class Lcom/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentChange; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentChange' appears in /data/app/packagename-yHh4aIRPAZwxxRYgunJivQ==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
at com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreArray.onDocumentAdded(FirestoreArray.java:98)
at com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreArray.onEvent(FirestoreArray.java:83)
at com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreArray.onEvent(FirestoreArray.java:21)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.zzi.onEvent(Unknown Source:17)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeyn.zza(Unknown Source:6)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeyo.run(Unknown Source:6)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6809)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

The error states that the class `DocumentSnapshot` doesn't contain a method `getDocument` which after checking is correct. However this is also how FirebaseUI states this implementation in their documentation and I can't figure out where I'm doing something wrong.

The query used for the recycler
`Query query = mFirestore.collection("spots");`, The collection is present and has `documents` within.

The adapter with query

```
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));

            Query query = mFirestore.collection("spots");
            FirestoreRecyclerOptions<SpotModel> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<SpotModel>().setQuery(query, SpotModel.class).setLifecycleOwner(this).build();

            mAdapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<SpotModel, SpotHolder>(options) {
                @Override
                public SpotHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_spot, parent, false);

                    return new SpotHolder(view);
                }

                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SpotHolder holder, int position, @NonNull SpotModel model) {
                    holder.bind(model);
                }
            };

            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

FirebaseUI dependencies

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.2.2'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.2.2'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:3.2.2'
```

The adapter is being initialized in the `onCreateView` method of a fragment. I followed the instructions on the Github page of FirebaseUI but without success ([link](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/firestore#using-firebaseui-to-populate-a-recyclerview))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try not to double post.

For everyone else: this is a [known issue](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/1210) and will be fixed in FUI 3.3.0 paired with Play Services 12.0.1. For now, downgrading to Play Services 11.8.0 will do the trick.